# Flask CSRF: The CSRF session token is missing

Tags: python, flask, csrf, flask-wtforms

Can anyone guide me on how to use Flask-WTF CSRF protection when using Fetch? API docs doesnt seem to be clear on what to do with the CSRF token generated per request

I keep getting this error

```
The CSRF session token is missing.
```

and my javascript code:

```
let payload = {
            // some data,
          "X-CSRFToken": csrf_token
          }

    let header = {   'content-type': 'application/json','accept': 'application/json',"X-CSRFToken": csrf_token}
    paypal.Buttons({

        createOrder: function(data, actions) {
                    return fetch(prefix.concat("/payment/paypalCreate"), {
                      method: "POST",
                      headers: header ,
                      body:JSON.stringify(payload),
                      credentials: 'same-origin',
                      })
                        .then(function(res) {
                            return res.json();
                        }).then(function(data) {
                          console.log(typeof(data))
                            return data.id
                        })
                    .catch(err => {
                      console.log(err);
                    });
            }
```

Comment: You have to add the CSRF token to your request as documented in https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/csrf.html#javascript-requests .

Comment: @KlausD. i actually did. it seems that its checking the session data. do also need to set the CSRF token in sessions? the errors states that "The CSRF session token is missing".

Answer (score 0):

use **CSRF** from Flask_cors and wrap your application in that. You won't need to use csrf_token explicitly then. Refer [FLASK-CORS](https://flask-cors.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for usage.